Why am I able to see a lookup record's name field if I don't have access to the record
I have an Object A and that has a look up to an Object B. There is a record A1 in Object A and there is a record B1 in Object B. Record B1 is a lookup on A1. The user has access to record A1, but does not have access to B1. But when I generate a pdf through visualforce, I am able to query the value on ObjectB__r.Name and display it on the pdf. There is a field Date__c on Object B and that is coming as empty, which it should. But I can see the name field on the pdf even through they don't have access to the record.
I was expecting the name field not to be visible either. Why is the user still seeing the Name field even through they don't have access to the data.

If your vfp is using a custom controller, then consider using the "with sharing" keyword to potentially circumvent your issue.
Another tool to consider could be permission-gating lookup names by requiring record access to read them, more on that here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_require_permission_lookup.htm&type=5

It is a custom controller and I already have with sharing on the custom controller. I have seen the "Require Permission to View Record Names in Lookup Fields" article, but I wasn't sure if this also controls SOQL in visualforce controller as well. In the article, it states "After the Require permission to view record names in lookup fields setting is enabled, in Lightning Experience, users who don’t have Read access or the View All Lookup Record Names permission see the lookup field labels, but not the data in the fields." Are you saying this also control's the SOQL Query in the controller?

Maybe the user is seeing the name field in the "with sharing" vfp query context because they somehow have record access.   Perhaps an admin with the capability to 'login as' that user (from user detail page) could impersonate + attempt to view the record ID's detail page in browser.  If that access test fails then its something else.  Without doing this myself, my guess is that something (OWD, or manual share, or apex share, or role hierarchy, or some other record access grant mechanic) is giving them record access.  If object B is Private OWD you could locate / use the "Sharing" button to see

Before looking into that permission and whether it affects your query,  you first might want to locate Object B's OWD page, and see how its "Require permission to view record names in lookup fields" is defined, along with the earlier steps to locate what, if anything, is giving the user record access to b1 record.

I logged in as that user and tried accessing the B1 record and they do not have access. The Visualforce page is also querying a field called Date__c on that object and that is returning as empty even though its not, so somehow, they are able to see the name field, even though they don't have access.

In Sharing Settings, The "Require permission to view record names in lookup field" is unchecked.
In the profile, The permission "View All Lookup Record Names" is unchecked.

First, not sure why we have two different permissions. My guess and this is just an assumption, The setting in Sharing Setting control's if they need permission to view the name from lookup field. The permission on the profile controls if they have access to the name field or not. If the permission on Sharing setting is unchecked, I guess they can see the name. Is my assumption correct?

I think you are right, that would make sense to me.
